# reverse array and set button

Tags: java, android

I want set value to button of array. but i want set value  reverse of button and array.if was array setDay[100], and 31 number button, set value setday 100-1 and button 31-1.

print out

```
Blockquote

 btn1  btn2  btn3  btn4  btn5 ....btn28  btn29  btn30  btn31

  69    70    71    72    73  ....  97    98      99    100
```

```
   int[] btnRes = {R.id.btn01, R.id.btn02, R.id.btn03, R.id.btn04, R.id.btn05, R.id.btn06, R.id.btn07, R.id.btn09,R.id.btn10, R.id.btn11, R.id.btn12, R.id.btn13, R.id.btn14, R.id.btn15, R.id.btn16, R.id.btn18,R.id.btn19, R.id.btn20, R.id.btn21, R.id.btn22, R.id.btn23, R.id.btn24, R.id.btn25, R.id.btn26,R.id.btn27,R.id.btn28,R.id.btn29,R.id.btn30};



/////// init buttons
      Button[] btnPrev = new Button[btnRes.length];

      for (int i = 0; i < btnPrev.length; ++i) {
          btnPrev[i] = (Button) findViewById(btnRes[i]);

      }

////// set value buttons to all buttons
      for (int i = 0; i < btnPrev.length; ++i) {

          btnPrev[i].setText(String.valueOf(setDay[i]));

      }
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int maxDays = 100;
int buttonsNbr = btnPrev.length;

for (int i = buttonsNbr; i > 0; i--) {

    btnPrev[buttonsNbr - i].setText(String.valueOf(setDay[ maxDays - i]));

}
```